# Erlang: How to access CLI flags (arguments) as application environment variables?

Tags: command-line, erlang, arguments, environment-variables

How does one access command line flag (arguments) as environment variables in Erlang. (As flags, not ARGV) For example:

RabbitMQ cli looks something like:

```
erl \
...
-sasl errlog_type error \
-sasl sasl_error_logger '{file,"'${RABBITMQ_SASL_LOGS}'"}' \
... # more stuff here
```

If one looks at `sasl.erl` you see the line:

```
get_sasl_error_logger() ->
   case application:get_env(sasl, sasl_error_logger) of
% ... etc
```

By some unknown magic the `sasl_error_logger` variable becomes an erlang tuple! I've tried replicating this in my own erlang `application`, but I seem to be only able to access these values via `init:get_argument`, which returns the value as a string.

How does one pass in values via the commandline and be able to access them easily as erlang terms?

**UPDATE** Also for anyone looking, to use environment variables in the 'regular' way use `os:getenv("THE_VAR")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you set up an application configuration file

```
{application, fred,
 [{description, "Your application"},
  {vsn, "1.0"},
  {modules, []},
  {registered,[]},
  {applications, [kernel,stdlib]},
  {env, [
    {param, 'fred'}
        ]
...
```

and then you can set your command line up like this:

```
-fred param 'billy'
```

I think you need to have the parameter in your application configuration to do this - I've never done it any other way...

Some more info (easier than putting it in a comment)

Given this

```
{emxconfig, {ets, [{keypos, 2}]}},
```

I can certainly do this:

```
   {ok, {StorageType, Config}} = application:get_env(emxconfig),
```

*but* (and this may be important) my application is started at this time (may actually just need to be loaded and not actually started from looking at the application_controller code).

Comment: Alan, thanks for the tip. I do have the param in my `.app` file. Good news: I get the default value specified in the `.app` file. Bad news: I can't seem to override it on the command line.

Comment: Nate, could you show us your app file and the command you start erlang with?

Comment: Yes - it should work so there's probably something fishy in your command line. Have you started your app by the time you access the environment?